# Python SQLAlchemy ORM - Table Reflection *without* Constraint & Index Reflection

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, sqlalchemy

I would like to use the SQLAlchemy ORM to Reflect (referred to in the docs as "Reflecting Database Objects") several tables.  All I am interested in is reflecting the Table DDL, not Index or Constraints - but this appears to be the default behavior.

Is there a way to disable the apparently default Index & Constraint Reflection?

This is what I'm doing:

```
from sqlalchemy import and_, create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

conn_str = f'oracle://{user}:{pswd}@{srvc}'
engine =  create_engine(conn_str, echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
meta = MetaData()

my_table = Table('my_table', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine, 
                 schema='my_schema')
```

With `echo=True` enabled, I can clearly see that the associated Index & Constraints are being reflected behind the scenes.  I do *not* want this to be done given the unnecessary database calls and overhead that it imposes on my app.  How do I disable the Index & Constraint reflection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesnt appear to be an obvious way to limit what happens under-the-covers when Reflecting a database object so I found that the best and most performant way around this is to simply define the mapped classes explicitly as described in the docs, only including the columns you require, as opposed to everything.

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'schema_name'}

    person_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
```

And then the query can be executed using the same `session.query()` syntax that would be used *with* the database reflection but saves you the significant overhead of going to the database dictionary tables.